# How do you install DrScheme 5.0.2?

Tags: scripts

I'm having trouble with DrScheme (or Racket). I want to install the 5.0.2 version of it and I downloaded a shell script. The problem is that when I open it it doesn't do anything.

WHat should I do?

Comment: Do you specifically need 5.0.2?

Answer (score 4):

You can try installing the version directly from the Racket Team PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plt/racket && sudo apt-get update
```

after that install it with

```
sudo apt-get install racket
```

That will be version 5.2.0-3 for Ubuntu 11.10 tough.

Answer (score 0):

The shell-script installer is meant to be run via `sh`, for example:

```
sh path/to/racket-5.0.2-bin-i386-linux-ubuntu-jaunty.sh
```

but the PPA approach is generally more convenient.  Either way, version 5.0.2 is very old, so you should consider getting the recent version instead.